# How to load a Hibernate association along with the parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem with associations in Hibernate.
I am trying to make an association between User and Customer.
Up to now I can write the association, but I don't know how to read it.

To save association I am using this:

This is for saving user in customer.java

```
private Set user = new HashSet();

    public Set getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Set user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

This one is for saving customer in user.java

```
private Set customer = new HashSet();

    public Set getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Set customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
```

I am creating customer and user and I am connecting them together.
After it, I try to get a list of all associations (user should have Customer id doesn't it?)

```
Long usrId = (Long) mgr.createAndStoreUser("Jack", "Plack");
    Long custId = (Long) mgr.createAndStoreCustomer("koko@koko.com");

    mgr.addUserToCustomer(usrId, custId);
    System.out.println("Added");

    List users2 = mgr.listUsers();
    for (int i = 0; i < users2.size(); i++) {
        User user = (User) users2.get(i);
        System.out.println(user.getUsername()+":"+user.getPassword()+" "+user.getCustomer());
    }
```

Here's how I am listing users:

```
private List listUsers() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        List list = session.createQuery("from User").list();

        session.beginTransaction().commit();

        return list;
    }
```

Here's how I am adding User to Customer:

```
public void addUserToCustomer(Long UserId, Long CustomerId) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        User anUser = (User) session.load(User.class, UserId);
        Customer aCustomer = (Customer) session.load(Customer.class, CustomerId);

        anUser.getCustomer().add(aCustomer);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Unfortunately when I try to list users, I am getting this:

> Hibernate: select user0_.USER_ID as USER1_4_, user0_.username as
>   username4_, user0_.password as password4_ from USERS user0_ Exception
>   in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to
>   lazily initialize a collection of role: airplane.User.customer, no
>   session or session was closed     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:358)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:350)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:343)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:309)
>     at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981)   at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)    at
>   airplane.Main.main(Main.java:46) Java Result: 1

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the `Customer` when you load the `User` entity:

```
List list = session.createQuery("select u from User u left join fetch u.customer").list();
```